# How To Install Thunderbird 24.0 on centos

Tags: centos, software-installation, thunderbird

How do I update thunderbird to latest version 24 on centos 6.3 (final) 64bit.

I cannot find any good tutorial on installing it on centos. Merely copying and pasting the 'thunderbird' folder in '/usr/lib64/' doesn't do anything.

The current version installed on my machine is 17.0.9

Comment: First of all what exactly are you trying to install - a `tar.gz` file downloaded from mozilla.org?

Comment: yes. I downloaded the file 'thunderbird-24.0.tar.bz2' from mozilla download page (linux specific).

Comment: mozilla packages are usually 32-bit - do you have 32bit compatibility packages?

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the thunderbird tarball from Mozilla. [Here is a direct link.](http://www.mozilla.org/thunderbird/download/?product=thunderbird-24.0&os=linux&lang=en-US)
2. Extract the tarball. `tar -xvf thunderbird-24.0.tar.gz`
3. Copy the folder into an install directory of your choice. `/usr/local` or `/usr/opt` are common choices.
4. Add the directory which contains your new Thunderbird binary to your `$PATH` environment variable. E.g. `export PATH=/usr/local/thunderbird-24.0/bin:$PATH` in
   `bash` or `setenv PATH /usr/local/thunderbird-24.0/bin:$PATH` in `csh`.
5. Run `thunderbird` from the terminal.
6. Add the command you ran in step 4. to the top of your `.bashrc` or `.cshrc` (or the equivalent for whatever shell you use) in order to have the `thunderbird` command available whenever you log in.

Answer (score 0):

In my phase, when I used to explore distros, I ran into CentOS. And CentOS is great, but the problem with CentOS was, that CentOS is mainly developed for server use, and he ran mostly older and stable versions of packages/libraries. In this case, it was really tough for me to install the newer versions of software because of the dependency problems (i.e. newer software depends on newer libraries which CentOS doesn't provide).

I won't say that this is impossible, but it isn't easy and if you are a desktop user, I would recommend you to install a distro like fedora or opensuse...